# ls: cannot access : No such file or directory

Tags: c, ls

When i type `ls` i get this message twice : `ls: cannot access : No such file or directory`. But when i type something like that `ls -l /tmp` or executing a "c" code located in the path everything is fine. Any ideas what is going wrong? 
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    for (;;) {
        char *cmd,*splitcmd,*pr0,*pr1,*pr2;
        int i, j, nargc = 0, characters;
        char **cmdArray;
        size_t bufsize = 1024;
        pid_t pid, wpid;
        int status = 0;

        printf("Type a command : \n");

        cmd = (char *) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
        characters = getline(&cmd, &bufsize, stdin);
        // printf("cmd===> %s  characters===>  %d \n",cmd,characters);
        if (cmd[characters-1] == '\n')
        {
            cmd[characters-1] = '\0';
            characters--;
        }
        // printf("cmd===> %s  characters===>  %d \n",cmd,characters);

        cmdArray = (char**) malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char *));
        for (i = 0 ; i < bufsize ; i++)
        {
            cmdArray[i] = (char*) malloc(bufsize*sizeof(char));
        }
        splitcmd = strtok(cmd," ");
        //   printf(" cmd====  %s\n",cmd);
        while ((splitcmd))
        {
            cmdArray[nargc] = splitcmd;
            if (cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc])) - 1] == ' ')
                cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc]))-1] == '\0';
            // printf(" nargc====%d  cmdArray===[  %s  ]                       \n",nargc,cmdArray[nargc]);
            nargc++;
            pr0 = cmdArray[0];
            pr1 = cmdArray[1];
            pr2 = cmdArray[2];

            splitcmd = strtok(NULL," ");
            //printf(" pr0  %s   \n",pr0);
            //printf(" pr1  %s   \n",pr1);
            //printf(" pr2  %s   \n",pr2);
        }

        if ((pid = fork()) == 0)
        {
            char *argv[] = {pr0, pr1, pr2, NULL};
            execvp(argv[0],argv);
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                free(cmdArray[i]);
            }
            free(cmdArray);
        }
        wait(&status);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code, indent it and format it, etc. And do not cast the result of `void *` in c.

Comment: Does the code compile? And you can't execute a [tag:c] code.

Comment: It appears that `pr1` and `pr2` will point to junk data for the `ls` case. In other words, `cmdArray[1]` and `cmdArray[2]` are uninitialised for that case. And at a minimum it is confusing to be setting `pr0`, `pr1`, `pr2` inside the `while` loop before the command tokens have been completely split out.

Comment: It compiles and i can execute it. But i get the `ls: cannot access ...` message when i type `ls` for an input. @iharob

Comment: Then you didn't copy the "*actual*" code, see  this `if (cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc])) - 1] == ' ') cmdArray[nargc][(strlen(cmdArray[nargc]))-1] == '\0';`!

Comment: Yes i know that. But i need them in case the input is something like `ls -l /tmp`. Any suggestions? @kaylum

Comment: Argh! So you know you are using junk values and you still continue to do that and have made no attempt to fix that or tell us that you are knowingly leaving bugs in your code? At least you could point that out if you do indeed already know that is an issue. The fix is to write your code to handle different number of arguments by making `argv` a dynamically sized array and only populate it with the right arguments.

Comment: What you mean? @iharob

Comment: I tried what you're saying. But with wrong if statement.
i made it now... thanks for the food for thought @kaylum

Comment: One more thing. Am i using correct dynamic allocation?@kaylum

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a number of problems, many of which are identified by turning on warnings.  Use `-Weverything` if your compiler supports it, or at least `-Wall` if it does not.  However, your particular question is in how you're calling `execvp()`.

```
char *argv[] = {pr0, pr1, pr2, NULL};
execvp(argv[0],argv);
```

This will *always* pass two arguments to `ls`.  Even if `pr1` and `pr2` are empty, `ls` will still act like it was passed arguments.  `ls` will determine how many arguments it has by looking for a NULL entry.

Your code has a flaw in that it is trying to hard code the number of arguments by splitting up the `cmdArray` into individual variables.  This isn't going to work.  For starters, commands take more than two arguments.  You should instead leave `cmdArray` together, properly NULL terminate it, and pass that into `execvp`.